# Unable to set session in chrome with codeigniter 3.0.0 but its set in firefox

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-chrome, session, firefox

I'm a beginner in codeIgniter.
I set session for check user login.
The sessions be set in firefox but doesn't set in chrome.
My code is like this:

in controller I have:

```
        $data_session=array(
            'username'=>$username,
            'login'=>true,
            'id'=>$id
            );
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
```

and In view I check session:

```
        if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
            echo $_SESSION['username'];
        }
```

Can anybody help me please?
Thanks

Comment: The session library is now a Driver in CI3.

Answer (score 0):

You should use like that:

```
if($this->session->has_userdata('username'))
{
   // todo
}
```

Comment: the sessions be set in firefox. I write this code with codeIgniter 3 guides.

Comment: @ArMeH Can you try change `sess_cookie_name` and `sess_expiration` in config file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use CI session library function instead of php session

try this

```
if (isset($this->session->userdata('username'))) {
            echo $this->session->userdata('username');
}
```